# how to make a checkbox category bar in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I made a function in CodeIgniter so someone clicks on a category in the category side bar it will link to a new page with that category id and show all the products that have the same category id.

Now what I want is that you can select multiple categories with checkboxes at the same time on the same page but I don't know how to do it.

Here I'm linking the category sidebar on the view page:

```
<div class="categorieen">
      <?php foreach (get_categories_h() as $category) : ?>
  <input id="box1" type="checkbox" />
  <label for="box1"><a class="listcat" href="<?php echo base_url().'Product/category/' . $category->id; ?>"> <?php echo $category->name; ?></a></label>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

With db_helper.php file I'm getting categories from database:

```
<?php if (!function_exists('get_categories_h')) {
    function get_categories_h(){
        $CI = get_instance();
        $categories = $CI->Product_model->get_categories();
        return $categories;
    } } ?>
```

Category_model find function :

```
<?php


class Category_model extends CI_Model {


    public function find($id)
          {
              $this->db->where('id',$id );
              return $this->db->get('categories')->row();
          }

}


?>
```

functions in Product_model:

```
/** Zoek alle products in table products met deze functie (word gebruikt voor categorieen) **/
    public function findAll(){
        return $this->db->get('products')->result();
    }


     /** Zoek category_id in table products  **/
       public function findByCategory($category_id)
       {
            $this->db->where('category_id', $category_id);
            return $this->db->get('products')->result();
          }
```

So yeah how can I change my code so instead of linking it to another page the user must be able to select multiple categories and show the products on the same page?

Comment: You don't know how to do it - YET!!!!!

Comment: Ok, could you show me please?

Comment: Hellloooo tim are you there sir?

Comment: HELP MEEEEEEEEEEEEEE

Answer (score 2):

You can bind the ajax call (call to the controller/action) to the change event of checkbox.

1) You can then fetch the products related to the checked categories and then return the required product details, build the HTML (client side) and replace the new HTML of products.

2) You can also build the HTML from the server side, you can return the HTML from the server side.

```
$this->load->view('product_html_file', $products,TRUE);
```

The above will return the HTML of the section you want to replace.Send it to the ajax response and replace the section

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm a beginning programmer and I don't have any knowledge of ajax, could you change my code for me please so the function will work please?

Comment: I can't write full code.You need to bit learn about ajax. Then you can apply the logic you need.Thanks.